# ios7 status bar color

Tags: hidden, ios7, status

For some reason in my app, when I go to a new tab in my tab bar controller, the first time that I go to that tab, the status bar is completely black. If I go back to that tab later, the status bar looks fine. I haven't touched any code regarding hiding the status bar and this problem only occurred when I switched to ios7 and xcode5. Anyone know how to fix it?

EDIT: I solved my problem by setting the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key to NO in the applications plist. However, only the black status bars work for me now. Both the opaque and transparent one are opaque and the default gray is just a purely black bar and you cannot see any of the text on the status bar. Any ideas?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, but couldn't get any solution. If you have found proper solution, then share with us..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your ViewDidLoad Method:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
    }
```

It fixed status bar color for me and other UI misplacements also to a extent.